# Attributetext not showing on category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, attributes, php-7

Trying to show an attributetext of an attribute at each product on category pages. Got the following code:

```
<?php
    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
    $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());
    $attributeset = strtolower($attributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName());
    if($attributeset == 'seeds'):
    echo '<div class="qty-seeds">' . $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('qty_seeds')->getStoreLabel() . ': ';
    echo $_product->getAttributeText('qty_seeds');
    echo '</div>';
    endif;
?>
```

The label does show but not the text... any one know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was enabling '***Show in Product Listing***' for the relating attribute